# EDIT TEXT auto height increment

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

This image has edit text when I enter the long message it not showing all line it showing just one line but all line are at up on the view line how to solve. I just want to know how to do this like second image in the below like WhatsApp edittext

[image]

Comment: Please post your code (or a minimum example)

Comment: post your code here

Comment: It seems you are using Fixed fight for your Edittext
Or Your layout design fixed your EditText hight like layout below some view that has a fixed size or the EditText root view has a fixed size

Comment: post your xml code

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

```
<EditText 
   ...
   android:inputType="textMultiLine"
/>
```

Comment: what if he fixed the height of the Edittext?

Comment: The min-height attribute can be used in this case.